# django tastypie - api authentication ? its server for ios app

Tags: python, ios, django, python-2.7

I am building IOS app that talks to django server for getting the data.

This app uses facebook authentication for login, so I am thinking like this:

In IOS app, after clicking login button(fb auth), we will get userdata(like username, email etc from facebook) and access_token. I will store username and accesstoken in IOS app somewhere(like session) and for every call to server for getting data, I will send these 2 also(username and accesstoken).

In the server, tasty pie has something like Authentication that can be customised like this:

```
class SillyAuthentication(Authentication):
def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)  -- username sent from ios app.

    #checking token sent now with the token saved during registration.
    #I hope, fb sends same authtoken everytime he logins.
    if user.userprofile.access_token == access_token: 
      return True

    return False
```

So, this means, everytime request is sent from ios app, it need to send username, accesstoken. This is what I got to mind, but not sure if I am right or wrong .

Comment: to access headers, use the request.META dictionary  (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/ )

Comment: Yeah, I came to know about this. But, Is my procedure correct? Also, for getting list of things, I use tastypie. But, what if I want to do things like registration, etc. Need to follow tastypie api or I can write separate views that has urls similar to api ?